# How to draw two progress bar in jsp using the 4 variables of dates in java

Tags: java, jsp, progress-bar

I need to draw an progress bar according to dates and null values from the variable in jsp

im declared like this in jsp

project variables:

> ```
>  Estimated start date = "2013-06-08"
>  Estimated end date = "2013-06-10"
>  Actual Start Date = "2013-06-12"
>  Actual End Date = "2013-06-14"
> ```

scriplets  jsp:

```
<% 
        ArrayList list;
        Session hibernateSession;
        hibernateSession=NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String projectname="",desc="";
        String strtdate="",acstrtdate="",enddt="",acenddate="";
        String Msg="";
        int projid;
        int q=0;
        list = (ArrayList)hibernateSession.createQuery("FROM entity.NewProject").list();
        int proj_count=list.size();
        for(int i=0;i < proj_count;i++)
        {
        Object projects=list.get(i);
        NewProject project1 = (NewProject)projects;
        projectname = project1.getProj_name();
        projid=project1.getIdnew_proj();
        desc=project1.getProj_desc();
        strtdate=project1.getStrt_date();  // Estimated start date
        enddt=project1.getEnd_dt(); // Estimated end date 
        acstrtdate = project1.getActual_start_date(); // Actual Start Date
        acenddate = project1.getActual_end_date(); // Actual End Date 
        q++;


    %>
```

Actually i need two progress bars one is for estimated start date and end date and another one is for actual started date and end date
What i need is

I have to compare the both start date are same date. If not it is delayed.  Write the progress bar until the actual end date in different colour.

Similarly another scenario the Estimated start date & actual start date is same . But the if you compare end date and actual end date it may be having different dates. So it is. Delayed. and need to draw the progress bar of the delayed in separate colour

Please help any help will be appreciated more and more and more.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your codes

Comment: Kindly check my scriplet code and see